# pulling from remote branch while on another branch - "pull origin main" vs "pull main" vs "change to main then pull"

Tags: git

i'm a little confused pulling from remote branches while being on another branch.
for example, if I change to main, then pull:

`git checkout main`
`git pull`
I get updated with the remote changes. good.

but, if i'm on another branch and I want to update main without changing to main, I always get results that confuse me (I don't really get the updates unless I change to main).

let's say i'm on branch 'feature', and I try:
`git pull main` or `git pull origin/main` or `git pull origin main`, I get something I didn't expect, but never the updated branch.

a specific example, running `git pull origin main` while being on branch `feature`, will output this:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
From <repo name>
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   8a84194..d00d469  master     -> origin/main
Updating 340286a..d00d469
Fast-forward
```

But when I change into main `git checkout main`, then `git pull`, I get the actual updates:

```
git pull
Updating 8a84194..d00d469
Fast-forward
 Pipfile      |    2 +-
 Pipfile.lock | 1583 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------------------------------------------
 setup.py     |    2 +-
 3 files changed, 863 insertions(+), 724 deletions(-)
```

Can you please help me understand what am I getting wrong?
Thank you!

Roy.

Comment: `git pull` does `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, and that tries to merge into the branch you've got checked out. You should use `git fetch` instead. That will update `origin/main`, though not `main`. To update `main` itself after such a fetch, you can checkout main as you were doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you literally *can't* merge into anything other than the branch you have checked out *right now*.<sup>1</sup>

Second, what `git pull` means<sup>2</sup> is:

1. run `git fetch`, then
2. run a second Git command.

That second Git command is your choice, but without making an explicit choice, you generally get `git merge`.  So `pull` = `fetch` + `merge`, and `merge` only works on the *current branch*.

(Your other normal option is `git rebase`.  But `git rebase` has this same constraint of only working on whatever branch you have checked out *right now*.  It too has some footnotes because Git can't stand to leave anything simple, but again we'll ignore these.)

So, to a first approximation:

- `git pull` means *pick the* upstream *for this branch, and then pull into this branch* (we'll define *upstream* later);
- `git pull origin main` means something complicated, which I'll describe later; and
- `git checkout main` and then `git pull` means *pick the upstream for `main`, and pull into `main`* since "this branch" is `main`.

*Unless you're already on `main`*, **none of these three commands can be exchanged for any of the others**.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are a number of caveats to this—special cases that *seem like* merging, for instance, and upcoming future Git software that may eventually escape this constraint—but for now just take it as Truth.

<sup>2</sup>In the old days (as in before 2015, before Git 2.6), `git pull` was literally a shell script that ran `git fetch`, and then ran the appropriate second command.  The C version is faster and more efficient, but the logic is still the same internally.

---

#### The necessary background, without which Git never makes any sense

You probably use Git to maintain a bunch of files.  But Git isn't really *about* files.  You also use branches, but Git isn't about *branches* either.  In the end, Git is all about *commits*.  It's true that commits *contain* files, and we use branch names to help us (and Git) *find* commits, but Git isn't about the files or branch names: it's *raison d'être* is the *commit*.

You therefore need to know what a Git commit is and does for you.  Fortunately this part is pretty simple.  A Git commit:

- Is numbered.  Each commit gets a *unique* hash ID.  The hash ID is huge and ugly and random-looking, and impossible for humans to remember.  It *has* to be, because it has to be *unique:* when you make a new commit, it has to get a number that has never been used before, and now that number can never be used again for any *other* commit.

  (This part is mathematically impossible due to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), but by being huge, the hash IDs push off the inevitable failure well into the future, by which point we all plan to be dead, so that we don't care. )

  Because each commit *has* a unique number, we can take any two Git repositories and introduce them to each other briefly, with `git fetch` or `git push`.  One Git is a sender and one is a receiver.  The sender lists out his commit hash IDs, and the receiver checks to see if he has those hash IDs.  If he does, he has *those commits*.  If not, he can tell *which commits he already has* and *which commits he needs* and the receiver then has the sender send over any commits the receiver needs.  And now the two Git repositories share commits.  (You have to connect them twice, once in each direction, to get complete sharing, and there are a bunch of ways to *limit* the sharing, but that's the general principle.)
- Is completely read-only: no part of any commit can ever be changed once it's made.  This is necessary to make the hash ID trick work.
- Contains two things: a *full snapshot of all of the source files*, frozen for all time in the form they had when you (or whoever) made the commit, and some *metadata*.  The metadata include things like your name and email address and the date-and-time-stamp from when you made the commit.  But there's a bunch of other stuff in the metadata, and in particular Git adds its own *list of earlier commit hash IDs*.

This list-of-earlier-commit-hash-IDs, inside each commit's metadata, *connects* the commits, backwards.  Most commits (by far) have exactly one such hash ID, and those are the ones we'll concentrate on first.  When we do have exactly one hash ID, Git calls this one hash ID the *parent* of the commit.  We say that the commit *points to* its parent.  This gives us a way to draw commits.

Let's say that the *latest* commit in your repository has some big ugly hash ID that we'll just call `H` for "hash".  Commit `H` stores the hash ID of some earlier commit: a different, big-ugly-random-looking thing that we'll call `G`.  That means that commit `H` *points to* earlier commit `G`:

```
          G <-H
```

But `G` is a commit, so it too has one hash ID stuck in *its* metadata.  It points to some earlier commit; let's call that one `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Commit `F` has metadata, so it points back to yet another earlier commit, and this just keeps going forever—or at least, until we get back to the *very first commit ever*, which literally *can't* point back to anything earlier.  So it doesn't: it has an *empty* list of previous commits.  If we call that commit `A` (and claim that we have exactly 8 commits), the entire chain is:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H
```

where I've gotten lazy about drawing the arrows *as* arrows.  They're each a part of a commit and can never change: `H` *always* points backwards to `G`, forever, and `G` points backwards to `F` forever, and so on.

For all this to work, Git needs a fast way to *find* commit `H`.  Git in general files all of its internal objects—commits and their supporting stuff—by their hash IDs, using a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) indexed *by* hash ID.  So the fast way for Git to find `H` is to know its hash ID.

Now, you *could* memorize each of your Git commit hash IDs.  But [that way madness lies](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/that+way+madness+lies).  Instead of *us* memorizing hash IDs, why not have the *computer* do it?  This is where branch and other names come in:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

The *branch name* `main`—which is a changeable pointer, unlike the pointers stuck inside commit metadata—tells us *which commit is the newest one **on** `main`*.  If we make a *newer* commit `I`, Git will arrange for `I` to point backwards to `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I
```

and will then re-point the *name* `main` to the newer commit:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I   <-- main
```

and now the newest commit "on" `main` is commit `I`, not commit `H`.

#### More branch names = more pointers

Let's go back to this setup, with just one branch name `main`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

and now let's create a *new branch name*, such as `develop`.  In Git, a branch name *must* point to *exactly one commit*.  We could pick any of our eight commits, but the most appropriate one here is probably the *latest* one, and if we use `git branch develop` to create it, that's the one Git will pick here.  Now we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, main
```

At the moment, *both names select commit `H`*, but once we start making *new* commits, this will change.  So we need to know which *name* we are using to find commit `H`.  To mark that in our drawings, let's attach the name `HEAD`, in all uppercase like this, to exactly one branch name:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

We're using commit `H` right now, but doing so through the *name* `main`.  If we run:

```
git checkout develop     # or git switch develop, which does the same
```

we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

We're still *using* commit `H`, but we are doing so through the *name* `develop` now.

If we make our new commit `I` now, it gets made the same way it would have if we were on `main`, but since we're using `develop` now, it's *this* name that gets updated:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The name `main` doesn't move, because it's not the name we're *using*.

This is a general rule in Git: whenever you make a *new commit*, Git will update the *current branch name*.  That's the name to which `HEAD` is attached.  So if you draw your commits (on paper or a whiteboard, or use `git log --graph` to get Git to draw them), you'll see where you are now and where the new commit will go.  It will *add on*, right after whatever commit you're using, through whatever name you're using.

#### Let's look at `git merge` now

Suppose we start out with:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

and make two new branch names, `br1` and `br2`, also pointing to `H`.  We'll also soon stop drawing in the *name* `main` just to de-clutter the drawings a bit.  So now we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, br2, main (HEAD)
```

We now pick `br1` to be the *current* branch and make a new commit:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

When we make a second commit we get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

We then switch to the branch-name `br2`, so that we get back to the saved files from commit `H`, and start making some different changes on `br2`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

If we `git switch br1` again we'll have Git replace the commit-`L` files with the commit-`J` files and be "on" `br1` again:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and if we now run:

```
git merge br2
```

Git will do the complicated process of merging.  Skipping right over the *how* part, let's look at the *result* of merging: if all goes well, Git makes a new *merge commit* `M`.  What makes `M` a merge commit is that, instead of *just* pointing back to commit `J`, as any new commit would, it *also* points back to commit `L`, like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

(and now you know why I stopped drawing in the name `main`: it's still there, it's just hard to draw it *and* commit `M` too).

This is a *true* merge.  To achieve it, Git has to *combine work:* Git has to figure out what changed between `H` and `J`, and what changed between `H` and `L`.  We've skipped over this *and* how Git chooses commit `H` in the first place, but the fact is that Git *does* choose `H` here.  Commit `H` is the best *shared* commit, on *both* branches `br1` *and* `br2`.  All commits up through and including `H` are on both branches.  Git calls `H` the *merge base* for this merge operation.

Then Git has to make a new snapshot for commit `M` that applies the *combined* work to the snapshot from `H`, thus either keeping your changes and adding theirs, or—if you like to look at it the other way around—keeping their changes and adding yours (note that the result is the same either way, for a normal everyday merge).

This kind of work-combining requires that one of the two branches be checked out.  The merge commit `M` is *added to* that branch, which is why `br1` now points to `M`.  The other branch names don't move: only the *current* name is affected by adding a new commit.

**Not all merges are true merges.**  Suppose that instead of making two branches `br1` and `br2`, and making new commits *on* the two branches, we start with `main` and `br1` and make two commits on `br1` only, then switch back to `main`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

If we now run `git merge br1`, here's what Git does:

- It figures out the best shared commit that's on both branches.  That's commit `H` again.
- For a true merge, Git would have to find what work was done between commit `H` and commit `H` ("our" side of the merge), and what work was done between commit `H` and commit `J` ("their" side of the merge).  But commit `H` *is* commit `H`.  There's no work at all on "our" side!

Since the merge base commit *is* the *current* commit, as selected by following `HEAD` to the branch name to the commit, there's no *divergent work to merge*.  The result of doing a real merge would be a merge commit whose snapshot exactly matches the existing snapshot *in* commit `J`.

Git's `git merge` therefore takes a short-cut.  You can tell it *not* to do so, with `git merge --no-ff`, but by default, Git does a *fast-forward* **instead of** a merge.  (Git calls this a *fast-forward merge*, but there's no actual merging involved.)  To do this, Git simply slides the current *branch name* forward to point to the other commit, and then checks out that commit as if by `git checkout`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1, main (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
```

(there's no reason to bother with the kink in the graph any more, but I left it in for now).

Note that, like a regular merge, this fast-forward merge *moved the branch name*.  It didn't make any *new commits* though, and that's what makes it special.  **The fact that it did not make any new commit means that in the future, we may never know that Git did this.**  If we erase the *name* `br1` now, we get:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- main (HEAD)
```

and it looks like we just made the commits *on* `main` all along.

#### Let's return to `git fetch`

I already mentioned `git fetch` in the basic background section.  This is how you connect *your* Git software, working on / with your Git repository, to *some other* Git software—anything that speaks the Git protocol, really—that's working on / with some other repository.  If we call the your-software-plus-your-repository "your Git" and the other-software-plus-other-repository "their Git", this:

- gets from their Git any commits they have that you don't, and
- has your Git create and/or update some names.

The trick here is that the names your Git creates and/or updates are not *branch* names at all.  The reason for that is that your branch names are *yours*.  *You* made `br1` and `br2` (or didn't).  Your `main` is keeping track of commits *you* have added.  Overwriting these names, to keep track of some other Git's commits, would be bad!

So your Git does not do that at all.  Instead, your Git takes each of their Git's *branch* names, such as `main` and `develop` and `feature/tall`, and sticks `origin` (or some other name, but let's go with `origin`) and a slash in front of each one.  Their `main` becomes your `origin/main`, their `develop` becomes your `origin/develop`, and so on.

Your Git now creates or updates *these* names, which are your Git's way of remembering their Git's *branch* names.  So now you might have:

```
          I--J   <-- main (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/main
```

in *your* repository, or maybe:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/main
```

depending on what you did with *your* branch names.  *Their* `main`—your `origin/main`—has moved from pointing to `H`, which you had earlier, to pointing to `L`, because *they* added two commits that you didn't have.  Your Git got those two commits from their Git, and put them in your repository, and they now have the same hash ID as their Git's two commits because they are the *same* commits: bit-for-bit identical in terms of saved snapshot and metadata, including parent hash IDs.

If you run `git checkout main` to get this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/main
```

you can now run `git merge origin/main`.  Your Git will find the *merge base*, commit `H`, for this operation, and notice that this does not require a true merge and can do a fast-forward instead, and you will get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

in your own repository (this time I straightened out the kink).

Note that these `origin/`-prefixed names are not *branch* names.  I call them *remote-tracking names*.  Git's documentation calls them *remote-tracking branch names*, but they are not *branch* names at all: they're reflections of someone else's branch names, but they're not actually *branch* names in *your* repository.

#### Hang on, we're almost there: *upstream* of a branch

Let's now talk about the upstream setting of a branch.  Every *branch* name in your repository (but not any remote-tracking name) can have *one* upstream set.  This is optional, so each branch name can have *no* upstream.  Setting an upstream doesn't change the branch in any way.  It just makes certain operations more convenient:

- If you run `git merge` without naming anything, Git will use the *upstream* setting of the current branch.  That is, `git merge origin/main` means *find the commit named by `origin/main`*, and `git merge` means *find the commit named by the current branch's upstream*.
- If you run `git rebase` without naming anything, Git will use the upstream of the current branch.
- If you run `git pull`, Git will use the upstream of the current branch.
- If you run `git status`, Git will add to the status some information obtained by using the upstream of the current branch.

These aren't the only things, but they're kind of the highlights, as it were.  Setting an upstream makes Git more *pleasant to use*.  But you do, alas, only get *one* per branch name, and you should almost always set that one upstream *to* the corresponding remote-tracking name.  That is, the upstream of `main` should be `origin/main`, the upstream of `develop` should be `origin/develop`, and so on.

(There's a little glitch in this: when you make up your own new branch name—`feature/roy` for instance, or `br1`, or whatever—there *is no corresponding branch* over on `origin` yet.  So there's no `origin/roy` or `origin/br1` and you can't *set* the upstream yet.  Git makes you wait until you've used `git push`.  We'll touch on that a bit more later.)

#### Putting it all together

We now know that:

- `git fetch` gets new commits from some other Git (e.g., at `origin`) and updates the corresponding remote-tracking names; and
- `git merge`, run by itself, merges with the *upstream*, doing a fast-forward or true merge as necessary.

Running `git pull` first checks that there is an upstream set (so that it can do the `git merge` step), then does both of these commands for you.  That's all it really does.

But wait, hang on, what about `git pull origin main`?  Well, if you don't have an upstream set yet—or even if you do—`git pull origin main` will let your command run.  First, `git pull` passes the whole rest of the line *to* `git fetch`, so that you have run:

```
git fetch origin main
```

The `git fetch` command normally uses the upstream (`origin/main` for instance) to know to go over to `origin`, but here we tell it explicitly "use the Git over at `origin`".  The final `main` here tells it which of *their* branch names we're particularly interested in: it *limits the fetch*.  Normally your Git would have their Git list out *all* their branch names, and bring over *all* their new commits.  With this command, your Git only asks their Git for new commits they have on their `main`.

(This usually is no savings at all because you'll need their other commits from their other branches later, and if you get everything at once, that's actually *more efficient* than if you run multiple `git fetch` operations.  But it will speed up *this* `git fetch` a bit, sometimes; it's just that it will make a *later* `git fetch` slower than it would have been.  Save now, pay later, as it were.  Unless you have a horribly slow network connection or an unusually huge fetch, it's rarely worth doing.)

Anyway, having brought over any new commits they had on their `main` or not, your Git updates your `origin/main`.  Then your `git pull` runs:

```
git merge -m "merge branch 'main' of <url> [into ...]" origin/main
```

(more or less—it actually uses a raw hash ID here, rather than the name `origin/main`, but the effect is the same).  So you get a merge that refers to the other Git's URL, and their branch name `main`.

Since no upstream setting is required, this will obtain their commits, update your `origin/main`, and then merge with your `origin/main`.  You can get the equivalent by running:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/main
```

although the *message* will now be:

```
merge branch 'origin/main' [into ...]
```

That is, only `git fetch` knew the actual URL used; by the time `git merge` ran it had no idea that `origin/main` had just now been updated from that URL.  The `git pull` code knew, because the `git pull` code *ran* `git fetch` for you, so the `git pull` code supplied an alternative log message.  (Neither log message is any good, really.  [They might as well just say `here have code` or `haaaaaands`.](https://xkcd.com/1296/))

#### Some notes on `git push`

Having made new commits in *your* repository, whether using `git commit`, or `git merge`, or `git merge`-as-run-by-`git pull`, or whatever, at some point you should *send* these new commits *to* some other Git.  The usual candidate here is the Git over at `origin`.  To push some commits, you will run, e.g.:

```
git push origin br1
```

The `origin` part here means *contact the Git that answers at the URL stored under the name `origin`*, i.e., the meaning is basically the same as that for `git fetch`.  The `br1` part here is how you supply two things:

- the *last* commit you need them to have (they'll get all the parents automatically), and
- the *branch name you want them to set in their repository*.

Note that unlike `git fetch`, which creates or updates *remote-tracking* names in your repository, a `git push` command supplies a *branch* name for them to set in *their* repository.  This is because there's no notion here of any remote-tracking names.  You typically choose *one* branch name you want them to set; when you use `git fetch` you typically want to get *all* of their branch names, and you don't know which names they have created, so we need something fancy like remote-tracking names.

Anyway, the result of all this is that your Git hands their Git your commits (on your `br1`, that they don't already have; your `br1` probably also has dozens or thousands of commits that they *do* have on their `main` or whatever and there's no need for your Git to send those as the two Gits have exchanged hash IDs and realize that these are already shared).  Then your Git asks their Git, politely, to create or update *their* `br1` to incorporate the new commits.

If they don't yet *have* a `br1`, they'll probably comply.  (Some hosting sites like Bitbucket and GitHub and GitLab add permissions rules, but base Git doesn't have any such thing.)  Or maybe they *do* have a `br1`: in this case, they will comply *only if the addition of those commits results in a fast-forward operation for them*.  That is, suppose you have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

and you run `git push origin br1`.  They have:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, main
```

If they put `I-J` into their repository, they can now slide the name `br1` forward so that they have all the commits you have, and their `br1` now points to `J` too.  But **if** they have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K   <-- br1
```

in *their* repository, and you give them `I-J`, the result on their side looks like this:

```
          I--J   [polite request: move `br1` here]
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K   <-- br1
```

If they do that, they will *lose* `K` off their `br1`.  That's because Git *finds* commits by reading the *branch names* and then working backwards, through those backwards-pointing arrows that connect commits to earlier commits.  Git can't go forwards as the arrows don't point forwards (and are part of the commits and can't be changed: they point backwards forever).  So for this case they will say: *no, I can't add `I-J` to my `br1` as that loses some commits*, which Git reports as a *non-fast-forward* error.

Note that `git push` *does not* run `git merge`.  It just tries to add commits as-is.  If you need to merge `I-J` with their `K`, you'll have to run `git fetch` to get commit `K` and get your `origin/br1` updated.  Then you can merge so that `I-J` *do* add on (in your repository):

```
          I--J-----------M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /              /
...--G--H   <-- main   /
         \ ___________/
          K   <-- origin/br1
```

Because new merge commit `M` points back to *both* `K` *and* `J`, this now adds on to *their* `br1` (your `origin/br1`) and they will accept a request that sends them `I-J-M` and asks them to set their `br1` to point to `M`.

(You also have the option to rebase instead of merging, but we won't go into this here.)

Now, for the case where they *didn't* have a `br1` before, you will have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
```

in your repository.  You *won't* have an `origin/br1`.  So you run:

```
git push origin br1
```

and send them `I-J` and ask them to *create* `br1`, and they obey.  Your Git sees that they accepted the polite request, and *now* your Git creates, in your repository, your `origin/br1`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1, origin/br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
```

You can now set the *upstream* of (your) `br1` to (your) `origin/br1`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/br1 br1
```

for instance.  But instead of making you type that out as a separate command, `git push` allows you to add the `-u` flag:

```
git push -u origin br1
```

The `-u` flag tells `git push`: *If the push succeeds, set the upstream of the just-pushed name to the corresponding remote-tracking name*.  That is, in this case, it means *set the upstream of `br1` to `origin/br1`*.  Note that if the push *fails*, the `-u` flag has no effect.

You can use the `-u` flag even if there's an upstream set now.  It will simply run the `git branch --set-upstream-to` command and *override* the current setting with the new one.  (If the upstream of `br1` is already `origin/br1`, this overrides the old `origin/br1` with `origin/br1`, so you can't even tell that anything happened.)  But most people prefer to keep "create new branch on `origin`" separate, in their heads, from "update existing branch on origin".  If you prefer this too, you'll know when you want to add `-u` (create branch there and set upstream here) and when you don't (update branch there, don't bother doing anything here).

Once you *have* set the upstream of `br1` to `origin/br1`, the usual Git settings mean you can just run `git push` while you're *on* `br1`.  So you only need `git push -u origin br1` *once*, when you're creating it, and after that you just run `git push` with no additional typing.

#### Conclusion

The three commands you outlined are all very different.  They are all built out of the fact that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second command, `git merge` by default*.  The *second* command, whatever it is, always operates on the *current branch*.

I personally prefer, most of the time, to run `git fetch` myself.  Then, for a case like a `main` that I don't do any work on, I may not even bother to keep `main` up to date.  I may even just *delete the name*.  I can just use the name `origin/main` instead: every `git fetch` I run updates my `origin/main`.  There's no need for me to keep my own `main` name.

Comment: "That is, git merge origin/main means find the commit named by origin/main, and git merge means find the commit named by the current branch's upstream." Does not `git merge origin/mean` mean merge the HEAD with origin/mean? Does not `git merge` mean merge my HEAD with the upstream of HEAD?

Comment: @Tryer: I assume `git merge origin/mean` was a typo for `git merge origin/main`. The way to think about this is that `git merge` needs to find the hash ID of at least one commit other than the current (`HEAD`) commit, in order to do anything useful. You give that hash ID on the command line: `git merge <hash>`. Or, because hash IDs are hard to type, you use a name that, with `git rev-parse`, would successfully *resolve to* a commit hash ID: `git merge origin/main`. The merge command does the hash-ID-resolving and proceeds. If you don't give *any* hash ID, `git merge` uses `HEAD@{upstream}`.

Comment: Besides "at least one hash ID, perhaps via a name, or perhaps by reading the upstream from the current branch", you can also select a *merge strategy* with `-s` and/or add options like `-X ours`, and if you run `git merge <hash1> <hash2> <hash3>` you've implied the `-s octopus` strategy. The actual merge is done not by `git merge` itself but rather by the strategy you request, so if you're not using the *standard* strategy, we have to inspect the strategy that you are using instead.

Comment: There are only a few strategies delivered *with* Git, though, so besides the standard one, we only really have to worry about `-s ours` (which works by ignoring the other hash IDs for the purpose of snapshot-making) and `-s octopus` (which is complicated: in particular I've never quite figured out how this one chooses its merge base). There's `-s resolve` but it's like a simplified `-s recursive`, and now there's `-s ort` but it claims to act like `-s recursive`.

Comment: "If you don't give any hash ID, git merge uses HEAD@{upstream}" I am trying to slowly internalize this. HEAD@{upstream} -- looking back at your answer, this means the "current branch's upstream" But what if the current branch, TryerLocal (HEAD) has no corresponding origin/TryerLocal ? I suppose current branch's upstream, where the current local branch is foo is origin/foo. My question is, suppose HEAD is foo and I simply run git merge, this is same as git merge origin/foo. Yes? what happens if there is no origin/foo ? Indeed, what happens if I am in a detached HEAD state and issue git merge?

Comment: @Tryer: either there is an upstream set (it's a string, sort of, via multiple `git config` settings with complications), or there isn't; `git branch -v` or `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name branch@{u}` will show what it's set to. For `git merge` with no other arguments to run, that *has* to be set *and* `git rev-parse` *has* to be able to turn that string into a hash ID. Otherwise you'll get an error message (one of Git's patented confusing ones  : `fatal: No remote for the current branch` is what I'm getting for no-upstream-set).

Comment: Note, however, that you can set the upstream of some branch name like `foo` to some other branch name like `bar` (`git branch --set-upstream-to=bar foo`). Then `git merge` with no arguments is equivalent to `git merge bar`, while on branch `foo`. So it really is "whatever the upstream is set to" (which then in turn has to be rev-parse-able to a commit hash ID).

Comment: `~/ppl$ git branch -v` gives
`* master 71de0f2fc Add braces.`
`:~/ppl$ git branch -vv` gives
`* master 71de0f2fc [origin/master] Add braces.`
In my case, it is the latter command that seems to indicate what the remote is set to.

Comment: @Tryer Ah, oops, I can never remember how many v's do what (especially because they fiddled with this at some point).

Comment: @torek - thank you for this amazing, detailed answer. not all heroes wear capes I guess.

Comment: @RoyCa Yes, torek is the git hero for me on SO. He is a gem.

Comment: @torek This answer should be a viral blog post. I haven't seen your other responses (commenters suggest they are equally great) but this deserves better than being stashed away under a fairly obscure SO question. Anyway, thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is, you need to merge the branch `main` to the branch `features`. When you run `git checkout features` and run `git pull origin/main` this will not update the branch `features` with the main commit. It will update the `main` only but not `feature`.

so what u need is.

1. Checkout again to branch main

   `git checkout main`
2. Pull the commit from main

   `git pull origin/main (or git pull)`
3. Change to `feature`

   `git checkout feature`
4. Merge the `main` to `feature`

   `git merge main`

And thats it. You got the commit from `main` to feature.